# pySpark local mode - loading text file with file:/// vs relative path

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am just getting started with spark and I am trying out examples in local mode...
I noticed that in some examples when creating the RDD the relative path to the file is used  and in others the path starts with "file:///". The second option did not work for me at all - "Input path does not exist"

Can anyone explain what the difference is between using the file path and putting 'file:///' in front of it ?

I am using Spark 2.2 on Mac running in local mode

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("test")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

#This will work providing the relative path
lines = sc.textFile("code/test.csv")

#This will not work
lines = sc.textFile("file:///code/test.csv")
```

Comment: Wouldn't `file:///code/test.csv` mean your path is `/code/test.csv` ?

Comment: if I put file:// I get an error "expected: file:///"

Comment: file:// expects a full path of the local file system. Since you are running on local mode, if you provide a relative path without file://, spark automatically generates the full path internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sc.textFile("code/test.csv")` means **test.csv** in `/<hive.metastore.warehouse.dir>/code/test.csv` on HDFS.

`sc.textFile("hdfs:///<hive.metastore.warehouse.dir>/code/test.csv")` is equal to above.

`sc.textFile("file:///code/test.csv")` means **test.csv** in `/code/test.csv` on local file system.